# Generic types constrained to be equal aren't convertible to each other

Tags: swift, generics, types, protocols

*First off: I'm using the Swift Development Snapshot 2018-02-13 (a), so perhaps that is causing the issue.*

---

I am having a problem with Swift's generics.
The issue revolves around a type that is generic over two type parameters:

```
struct Graph<Value, Edge: EdgeType>
```

`Value` is unconstrained and `Edge` is constrained to be an `EdgeType`:

```
protocol EdgeType: Hashable {

    associatedtype Vertex_: VertexType

    //...
}
```

Now `EdgeType` has an associated type called `Vertex` constrained to be a `VertexType`:

```
protocol VertexType: AnyObject, Hashable {

    associatedtype Value_


    //... 
}
```

`Graph` has a nested type `Vertex`, which conforms to this protocol:

```
extension Graph {

    final class Vertex: VertexType { 

        typealias Value_ = Value // (`Graph`'s generic type parameter)

        //...
    }
}
```

---

The idea behind this hierarchy was, that `Graph` will use `Graph.Vertex` for its vertices, and constrain its generic `Edge` type parameter to use that vertex type as its `Vertex_`.
So I added a `where`-clause:

```
struct Graph<Value, Edge: EdgeType> where Edge.Vertex_ == Graph.Vertex { //... }
```

This would cause `Edge.Vertex_` and `Graph.Vertex` to be the same type.

---

*Now the issue:* When compiling I get the following error on multiple seemingly unrelated lines:

```
'Edge.Vertex_' is not convertible to 'Graph<Value, Edge>.Vertex'
```

The thing those lines all have in common is that they contain some statement concerning `graphTable`:

```
struct Graph<Value, Edge: EdgeType> where Edge.Vertex_ == Graph.Vertex {

    private var graphTable: [Vertex: Set<Edge>]
}
```

For example:

[image: Problem 1]

And if I change the type of the method's parameter I even get the following:

[image: Problem 2]

---

It seems to me that the compiler is just ignoring the `where`-clause and therefore does not recognize `Edge.Vertex_` and `Graph.Vertex` to be equal.

I am not sure though, so if anyone has an idea on what is going on I'd be happy to hear about it :)

Comment: Can you provide a code block that exposes the problem? I tried to put together once from the pieces you posted, however I'm not sure I combined them correctly :)